# Can valgrind report a memory address of a lost block (for debugging recursive function calls)?

Tags: c++, recursion, valgrind

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540063/how-can-i-get-valgrind-to-tell-me-the-address-of-each-non-freed-block-of-memory) question is the most similar to mine, but it's rather old, so I wonder if anything has changed since then.

The valgrind output for me is:

```
==29443== 109 (16 direct, 93 indirect) bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 270 of 309
==29443==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29443==    by 0x4F4E8DB: grl::Configuration::Configuration(grl::Configuration const&) (configuration.h:192)
==29443==    by 0x4F49973: grl::YAMLConfigurator::load(YAML::Node const&, grl::Configuration*, std::string const&) (configurable.cpp:74)
==29443==    by 0x4F499FC: grl::YAMLConfigurator::load(YAML::Node const&, grl::Configuration*, std::string const&) (configurable.cpp:75)
==29443==    by 0x4F499FC: grl::YAMLConfigurator::load(YAML::Node const&, grl::Configuration*, std::string const&) (configurable.cpp:75)
==29443==    by 0x4F499FC: grl::YAMLConfigurator::load(YAML::Node const&, grl::Configuration*, std::string const&) (configurable.cpp:75)
==29443==    by 0x40C78E: grl::YAMLConfigurator::load(std::string, grl::Configuration*, std::string const&) (configurable.h:321)
==29443==    by 0x40B897: main (deployer.cpp:180)
```

Program is configured at the start with recursive calls of reading from yaml file and storing all required parameters in a map as a pair `(name, allocated address)`. I can print these pairs. Therefore, if valgrind could tell me an address of lost values then I could get a name of a parameter and check why it is not freed.

If the functionality is not possible, what else can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your program under valgrind+gdb, using vgdb.
See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver

Then you can use various valgrind memcheck monitor commands to do
leak search and have the addresses/sizes of leaked blocks.
See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands